# is there any other function for from lesson_function import * to use for vehicle detection

Tags: python, algorithm, libraries

hello guys i am trying to write an algorithm for vehicle detection but cant go from importing libraries
because i get an error which is

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lesson_functions'
> and cant find any information at somewhere about the  lesson_functions

while importing libs bellow in notebook

```
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import glob
import time
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from skimage.feature import hog
from lesson_functions import *
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

also i am using python 3.7

Comment: chekc if you are using the custom module is it present there or not, seem like it is a custom module then a pip module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lesson_functions` is a custom user module which you are not importing, try checking the file from where you are referring there should be a module named `lesson_functions.py`. Download that and save it in the same directory as that of the file in which your main code is there. Then just import it by writing

```py
import lesson_functions
```